# Scala implicits resolution mechanism is declaration order dependent?

Tags: scala, implicit

During daily Scala coding I faced an issue that Scala implicits resolution depends on declaration order. A simple example:

```
object example extends App {
  trait FooTypeClass[T] {
    def foo: T
  }

  def bar[T](implicit tc: FooTypeClass[T]) = println(tc.foo)

  class A {
    // bar[A] doesn't compile
  }
  object A {
    implicit object aFoo extends FooTypeClass[A] {
      def foo: A = new A { override def toString = "a" }
    }
  }

  bar[A]
}
```

It does compile, but if I uncomment the commented line, it won't find the required implicit in scope. So, to make it compile I should place `object A` declaration before `class A`. That means my companions should go before their classes but I'd rather leave them as they are in the example.

Why does this order matter? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround keeping the order you wished:

```
object A {
    implicit val aFoo: FooTypeClass[A] = new FooTypeClass[A] {
      def foo: A = new A {
        override def toString = "a"
      }
    }
  }
```

I keep on seeking for the explanation why `object` (instead of `val`) doesn't fit.

Comment: Wow, it's interesting: if I omit type declaration after `val aFoo`, it won't compile as well. In fact, it infers `aFoo`'s type to be `FooTypeClass[A] with Object {def foo: A}` - some structural stuff. Type declaration fixes this. Still curious why `implicit object` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, at first time I omitted the type and Boum! :) Curious too for `object`

Comment: `object Foo extends Bar` implicitly creates anonymous class which extends `Bar`, so this seems to be identical to `val foo = new Foo with Bar` without type annotation. The questions is: why doesn't the compiler resolve its type to be `FooTypeClass[A]` and uses that structural type instead which looks much more complicated.

Comment: In general case, instantiating a trait `trait Foo` with `new Foo {}` gives back an instance of `Foo with Object` class. But this is not the case for abstract class. So, looks like this is the intentional compiler behavior. Interesting though...

Comment: Still can't understand why does changing the order fix the issue without changing `object` to `val`.

Comment: Can't find the explanation concerning `object` too

Comment: Implicits without explicit return types are not eligible in implicit searches higher up in the same file. Without this rule, the typechecker runs into cycles very quickly. Implicit object cannot have an explicit type ascribed; my recommendation is to avoid them in favour if implicit vals.