# Implicit value not found from companion object

Tags: scala

I have a function `foo` declared in `Bar` object:

```
package test
object Bar{
 def foo[T : A](b: T) = println(b)
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    foo(3)
 }
}
```

where `A` is declared in the same package:

```
sealed trait A[T]
object A {
  implicit object AInt extends A[Int]
  implicit object AString extends A[String]
}
```

in this configuration Bar object doesn't compile and produces this error message:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type test.A[Int]
    foo(3)
       ^
```

But when I place trait `A` and its companion object into package object `test` all work fine. Why?

**EDIT**

The problem is in order of declaration. If I place `A` typeclass declaration before `Bar` declaration everything works fine.

Comment: I think that even if you put the A object in the same package you still have to say import A._ in the main method, but I'm not sure why it works when you put it in the package object. Can you please post the working version with the package object usage?

Comment: I edited the title of this question.  "disjoint type" has a very specific and **very** different meaning in Scala.

Comment: Order matters. Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380800/scala-implicits-resolution-mechanism-is-declaration-order-dependent).

Comment: Could you please provide a transcript like the following that shows how to reproduce this error? https://gist.github.com/retronym/8435310

Comment: My suggestion: use implicit vals, rather than implicit objects, so that you can annotated the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the two solutions seem to be:

(1) Declare `A` first:

```
sealed trait A[T]
object A {
  implicit object AInt    extends A[Int   ]
  implicit object AString extends A[String]
}

object Bar {
  def foo[T: A](b: T) = println(b)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = foo(3)
}
```

(2) Use `def` or `val` with given return type:

```
object Bar {
  def foo[T: A](b: T) = println(b)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = foo(3)
}

sealed trait A[T]
object A {
  implicit def aInt   : A[Int   ] = AInt
  implicit def aString: A[String] = AString

  private object AInt    extends A[Int   ]
  private object AString extends A[String]
}
```

I would consider this is a compiler bug, but at least you can work around it.